# Are "plaquette de chocolat" and "tablette de chocolat" both correct?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage, synonymes, alimentation

*Alter Ego + 1* reports "une tablette de chocolat" as the only possible answer to a relevant exercise.

Le Petit Robert uses "plaque de chocolat" as an example in the "plaque" entry; in this same entry, it specifies a "plaquette" as a "petite plaque".

Comment: L'entrée *chocolat* du Petit Robert ne mentionne que *plaque* et *tablette*. Utiliser l'expression *plaquette de chocolat* ne peut être considéré comme réellement incorrect, simplement ça ne correspond pas à l'usage.

Comment: Literally *plaquette* is a a small *plaque* but some people use it instead of *plaque* probably because of the proximity with *tablette*.  See the entry "*Plaque, plaquette, palette*" in relation with *chocolat* on [Druide](https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/pause-chocolat). [On this specialised site](https://observatoire-des-aliments.fr/qualite/la-tablette-de-chocolat-une-valeur-sure) the words *plaquette* and *tablette* are use indifferently in the same paragraph. There might be regional differences. Personally I use either (France).

Answer (score 4):

**Tablette** est de loin le terme le plus courant.

[image]

Tablette désigne une plaque le plus souvent rectangulaire, prédécoupée par moulage, et par extension, peut aussi être utilisé pour parler de la musculature abdominale quand elle a un peu le même aspect.

Plaque et plaquette sont des synonymes plus rares.

On parle aussi de plaque de chocolat quand il s'agit d'une plaque sans démarcation de carrés, obtenue en refroidissant du chocolat fondu sur une surface plane.

Si le chocolat se présente sous forme allongée et épaisse, on parlera de barre de chocolat ou barre chocolatée quand elle contient beaucoup d'autres composants (par exemple du caramel).

Source: https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/pause-chocolat

Comment: À rapprocher : [plaquette de beurre](https://bit.ly/2Tzw5lg) vs [tablette de beurre](https://bit.ly/2ItOzxf).

Comment: Je ne sais pas si ce produit est connu hors de Belgique, mais on y trouve de petites plaquettes de chocolat (env. 10cm sur 10 cm, et 3mm d'épaisseur), destinées à être mises sur une tartine. De mon expérience personnelle, les consommateurs belges utilisent plutôt le nom *matinette* pour ces plaquettes, qui est le  nom du produit le plus courant de ce type. Cf. description ici: https://www.chocojacques.be/fr/matinettes-128g

Comment: @Greg "matinette" n'est pas le nom de ces choses dans l'absolu, c'est le nom commercial choisi par cette marque pour désigner ce produit. Je doute qu'un nombre important de belges soient capables de dire de quoi il s'agit si on leur pose la question dans la mesure où ce format est très particulier et propre à cette marque. Je ne connais en effet aucun produit similaire dans d'autres marques.

Comment: Entièrement d'accord, c'est ce que je voulais dire par "nom du produit", ce n'était pas clair: c'est un nom commercial.

Answer (score 3):

Personnellement, je n'ai jamais entendu *plaquette de chocolat*.
Dans mon entourage, on dit toujours *tablette de chocolat*.